# Steam Web API Key not working (Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your )

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I tried to get the GetMarketPrices query for the game Counter-Strike: Global Offensive and I get the following error

```
Forbidden
Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your

key=

parameter.
```

link

```
https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamEconomy/GetMarketPrices/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&appid=730
```

The X's are where my api key is, but I get this error

I tried to use https://steamapi.xpaw.me

Anyone who knows anything about the Steam API, please help.